# 400 Bad Request, works fine localhost

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get some information via php curl. It is working perfectly fine in my localhost wamp environment, but when I upload it online on my server, it says :-

```
400 Bad Request

nginx/1.9.12
```

Here is my code :-

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/addrs?token=some_token") 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($server_output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In API docs I don't see anything where token put in query for POST request.

So, I've checked Your code but put token as post field and it worked:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/addrs");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'token=some-token-here');

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($server_output);
```

docs: https://dev.blockcypher.com/?javascript#generate-address-endpoint